# Error when importing @aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner in react-native with expo in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, expo

It works in expo IOS, but when I open in browser with expo, the error message occurs with presigner import. Need some help here! Thank you!!

[image]

my code:

```js
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
```

```js
const data = new GetObjectCommand(bucketParams);
const url = await getSignedUrl(client, data);
```

(client was declared with no problem in putObject and getObject)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, inspired by https://github.com/akveo/react-native-ui-kitten/issues/996

In case anyone else runs to the problem.

First:
`$ npm i @expo/webpack-config`

Second:
Create `webpack.config.js` in root of app

Last, In `webpack.config.js`, add the following code:

```js
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require("@expo/webpack-config");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = async function (env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync(env, argv);
    config.module.rules.forEach(r => {
        if (r.oneOf) {
            r.oneOf.forEach(o => {
                if (o.use && o.use.loader && o.use.loader.includes("babel-loader")) {
                    o.include = [
                        path.resolve("."),
                        path.resolve("node_modules/@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner"),
                    ];
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return config;
};
```